# How is image/class used by the attention_ocr model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am preparing my own dataset to train the attention_ocr model. I am attempting to modify [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) to prepare my dataset. What is the purpose in specifying the [image/class/label](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py#L57) (for inception, for attention_ocr it appears to be [image/class](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/attention_ocr/python/datasets/fsns.py#L143)), and how is it used by attention_ocr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'image/class' feature is used to store character IDs, the attention_ocr uses this field as the [label](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/attention_ocr/python/datasets/fsns.py#L157) - the model learns to produce such sequence of ids using images as input. The mapping between character ids and actual utf8 characters is defined via TSV file specified in the [DEFAULT_CONFIG['charset_filename']](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3eba37c/attention_ocr/python/datasets/fsns.py#L44).

Comment: Thank you, I thought that is what 'text' was for, an the model converted to characters on it's own. Are you saying that the image/text is simply used for tensorboard, and debugging? I am attempting to prepare my own training dataset.

Comment: the current implementation uses only 'image/class', I doesn't use the 'image/text' feature even for debugging, it converts arrays of character ids to string using CharsetMapper  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/58a5da7/attention_ocr/python/model.py#L484